# Running Website on dedicated server it is giving error of Database that cannot find specified file

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The system cannot find the file specified
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error:

```
 string str = "select * from LatestTrades order by Tid desc";
 cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
 con.Open();
 sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 ds = new DataSet();
```

Comment: Which exact line of code is throwing that exception?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (preferably a console app).

Comment: i don't think the code you wrote can throw such exception.

Comment: `Please review the stack trace for more information about the error`

Comment: Check if you can connect to SQL server (Or and DB server) using connection string in your web.config.

Comment: Can you refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167505/2451726) to use the connection string in the SqlCommand

Comment: I got it actually it was the issue of server i did changes after then neither server was attaching .mdf files i opened database and table definition on my local pc and created new database and now it is working fine ...this problem always come when a user work with dedicated hosting